# Can we run rabbitmq (amqp) and nginx (http/https) behind haproxy listening on single port 443?

Tags: nginx, rabbitmq, haproxy

I would like to run both Nginx (HTTP/HTTPS) & RabbitMQ (AMQP) on 443 on same host under single IP. A possible solution that came to my mind is ha-proxy, which I am trying right now. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: May be we need more information on this, you already have NGINX why would you like to go for HAProxy or vice-versa what I mean is why do you need two proxies. And AMQP port is not `443` it runs on `5672`.